# MAMP Pro Get my virtual hosts to work with the suffix '.dev'

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

I just installed MAMP Pro (v2.x) and tried to create a vhost of `mydomain.dev` however it just did a Google search. When I try `dev.mydomain` and restart, it works fine. Any idea on what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the same issue.  However, it works when I prepend the protocol.  Try using http://mydomain.dev